# Jquery - Context menu - rightclick

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, background-image, right-click

I use a plugin for jquery - ContextMenu. - 
http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/

I have a div in the center of the page. I have the background-image in the points. I need it to only using jquery rightclick on the background-image. If you click on the background-image, so I want to display the ContextMenu. If you click the div with id divPage, nothing Happens.

Thanks for the advice or Possibly another solution.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<form id="formBackground" method="post">
<ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
                    <li class="insert"><a href="#insert">Add New</a></li>       
                    <li class="edit"><a href="#edit">Edit</a></li>                  
                    <li class="delete"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></li>            
                </ul>

    <div id="divPage">
Text.
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
}

body{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: white;
background-image: url('../images/backgrounds/bg.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:top;
}

div#divPage{
width: 800px;
height: 300px;
margin: auto;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('body').bind('mousedown', function (evt) {

                switch (evt.which) {       
            case 3:
            if(evt.target == $('body')[0]) {
                //Show context menu
            }
            break;
    }                

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating things.

Firstly I do not see your `List` anywhere in your code that creates the context menu.

Secondly all you need to do is:

```
$("idOfTheObjectYouWantToHaveAMenuOn").contextMenu({menu:"yourList"});
```

Comment: This is my list of menu -

    <ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
                        <li class="insert"><a href="#insert">Add New</a></li>  
                        <li class="edit"><a href="#edit">Edit</a></li>           
                        <li class="delete"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></li>   
                    </ul>

Answer (score 0):

why not let the contextmenu pop up when the div itself is clicked? if you need to show up the menu only by clicking on the bg image you need to put the image in the div itself and style it so it acts like an bg image. you can do this with css z-index and position absolute

Comment: I want to click only on the background-image.